# Kanboard install on Ubuntu 22.04.3 wrong url

Tags: apache2

I install kanboard on my ubuntu server 22.04

kanboard is installed in `/var/www/html/kanboard`

and in configuration for apache2 virtual host is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName kanboard.mydomain.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/kanboard

<Directory /var/www/html/kanboard/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is that when i try url http://kanboard.mydomain.local nothing is running but when i try http://kanboard.mydomain.local/kanboard now is kanboard running, what is wrong i my configuration when I need run kanboard on http://kanboard.mydomain.local

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the below?

1. Kanboard installation files are in '/var/www/html/kanboard' and not in '/var/www/html/kanboard/kanboard'?
2. You have disabled the default apache conf file using

```
#a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

3. Enabled the new site

```
#a2ensite exmaple.com.conf
```

4.cd into /var/www/html/kanboard and confirm the permission and file ownerships are correct.

```
chown -R root.root /var/www/html/kanboard/
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

5. Reload and restart apache2 after every changes.
6. Try above steps one by one and test the website and see if this fix for you.